# Apache Flink: How often is state de/serialized?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

How frequently does Flink de/serialise operator state? Per get/update or based on checkpoints? Does the state backend make a difference?

I suspect that in the case of a keyed-stream with a diverse key (millions) and thousands of events per second for each key, the de/serialization might be a big issue. Am I right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. It depends on the state backend.

Backends that store state on the JVM heap (`MemoryStateBackend` and `FSStateBackend`) do not serialize state for regular read/write accesses but keep it as objects on the heap. While this leads to very fast accesses, you are obviously bound to the size of the JVM heap and also might face garbage collection issues. When a checkpoint is taken, the objects are serialized and persisted to enable recovery in case of a failure.

In contrast, the `RocksDBStateBackend` stores all state as byte arrays in embedded RocksDB instances. Therefore, it de/serializes the state of a key for every read/write access. You can control "how much" state is serialized by choosing an appropriate state primitive, i.e., `ValueState`, `ListState`, `MapState`, etc.

For example, `ValueState` is always de/serialized as a whole, whereas a `MapState.get(key)` only serializes the key (for the lookup) and deserializes the returned value for the key. Hence, you should use `MapState<String, String>` instead of `ValueState<HashMap<String, String>>`. Similar considerations apply for the other state primitives.

The `RocksDBStateBackend` checkpoints its state by copying their files to a persistent filesystem. Hence, there is no additional serialization involved when a checkpoint is taken.

Comment: I think there is a little catch with the MemoryStateBackend and using de/serialization to create copies. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWQ24wERItM explains it, but I forgot the details...

Comment: Is there a way to configure Flink (with RocksDBStateBackend) so that it keeps the most recently accessed states in memory, and saves a lot of ser/deserialization ? The serialization could be done only for checkpoints or on LRU eviction. The ser/deser killed the performances in my app, taking 90% of the time spent in the processFunction

Comment: I'm sorry, a caching feature for the RocksDB state backend is currently not supported.

Comment: I watched the video that Caesar mentioned, here is where they talk about it. https://youtu.be/dWQ24wERItM?t=1148 . It will create a copy when getting it from heap state after a checkpoint while it's still asynchronously copying the data to the state file. This prevents the program from modifying the object while it's still being saved.